# Map dictionary values to key values in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe:

```
values
 NaN
 NaN
 [1,2,5]
 [2]
 [5]
```

And a dictionary

```
{nan: nan,
'1': '10',
 '2': '11',
 '5': '12',}
```

The dataframe contains keys from the dictionary.

How can I replace these keys with the corresponding values from the same dictionary?

Output:

```
values
 NaN
 NaN
 [10,11,12]
 [11]
 [12]
```

I have tried

```
so_df['values'].replace(my_dictionary, inplace=True)
so_df.head()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply()` method of pandas df. Check the implementation below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([np.nan,
 np.nan,
 ['1', '2', '5'],
 ['2'],
 ['5']], columns=['values'])

my_dict = {np.nan: np.nan,
 '1': '10',
 '2': '11',
 '5': '12'}

def update(row):
    if isinstance(row['values'], list):
        row['values'] = [my_dict.get(val) for val in row['values']]
    else:
        row['values'] = my_dict.get(row['values'])
    return row

df = df.apply(lambda row: update(row), axis=1)
```

Simple implementation. Just make sure if your dataframe contains string, your dictionary keys also contains string.

Answer (score 1):

### **Setup**

```
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'values':[np.nan,np.nan,[1,2,5],[2],5]})
my_dict={np.nan: np.nan, '1': '10', '2': '11', '5': '12'}
```

Use [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) with [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
df['values']=( df['values'].explode()
                       .astype(str)
                       .map(my_dict)
                       .dropna()
                       .astype(int)
                       .groupby(level = 0)
                       .agg(list) )
```

---

If there are others strings in your values column you would need [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors = coerce`, to keep it you should do:

```
df['values']=(pd.to_numeric( df['values'].explode()
                                         .astype(str)
                                         .replace(my_dict),
                             errors = 'coerce')
                .dropna()
                .groupby(level = 0)
                .agg(list) 
                .fillna(df['values'])
               )
```

**Output**

```
         values
0           NaN
1           NaN
2  [10, 11, 12]
3          [11]
4          [12]
```

**UPDATE**

solution without `explode`

```
df['values']=(pd.to_numeric( df['values'].apply(pd.Series)
                                         .stack()
                                         .reset_index(level=1,drop=1)
                                         .astype(str)
                                         .replace(my_dict),
                         errors = 'coerce')
                 .dropna()
                 .groupby(level = 0)
                 .agg(list) 
                 .fillna(df['values'])
         )
```

Comment: Nice, though does not quite qork with numerical values, and unclear what `nan` is here

Comment: Any alternative to .explode()? get an error saying AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: pd.__version__ yields 0.23.4

Comment: please see UPDATE section:)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['values']=pd.to_numeric(df['values'].explode().astype(str).map(my_dict), errors='coerce').groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```